# fibonacci series in perl executes to infinite loop

Tags: perl

Hi I am trying to execute fibonacci series with recursive function using perl. This is the code

```
#! /user/bin/perl

print "enter the number of elements for the series\n";
$value=<stdin>;
chomp($value);
print "\n\nThe value entered is $value\n\n";
for($i=0;$i<$value;$i++)
{
    print "fib($i)=".&fib($i);
    print "\n";
}


sub fib
{
    $rec=@_[0];

    print"In the subroutine rec is :".$rec."\n";
    if($rec == '0')
    {
        $f='0';
    }
    if($rec == '1')
    {
        $f='1';
    }
    else
    {
        $f=fib($rec-1)+fib($rec-2);
    }

    return $f;
}
```

But this code ends up in an infinite loop. Can anyone help with the mistake i have made.

Comment: The answers to this question point out how your code can be made to work, but there is still much to improve. If you'd like to have your code criticized, pop over to [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a problem if `$rec == 0`:

```
if($rec == '0')
{   # yes, this branch is being taken
    $f='0';
}
# ok, another conditional
if($rec == '1')
{   # nope
    $f='1';
}
else
{   # yes, this branch is taken: 0 != 1
    $f=fib($rec-1)+fib($rec-2);
}
```

… and suddenly you're executing `fib(-1)`.

Solution: Use `elsif` or return *immediately*:

```
return 0 if $rec == 0;
return 1 if $rec == 1;
return fib($rec - 1) + fib($rec - 2);
```

The next problem is that you're using global variables. If `$rec > 1`, the following happens:

- `fib($rec -1)` is being calculated, using the same `$rec` variable.
- At the end, `$rec == 0`.
- Now, we calculate `fib($rec - 2)`, which starts as `fib(-2)`.

Solution: use lexical variables with `my`:

```
sub fib {
    my ($rec) = @_;
    ... # the above code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the minimal modifies needed to make this script works:

1. In your `fib()`, if `$rec` is zero, then after `if($rec == '0')`, it will continue to test whether or not `$rec` equals '1', because `$rec` is '0', `fib()` will run `$f=fib($rec-1)+fib($rec-2);`, and you have an infinite loop.

   Therefore, `if($rec == '1')` should be `elsif($rec == '1')`.
2. By default, all Perl variable are global, but in this recursive implementation of `fib()`, variable `$rec` should be local or private, because in

   ```
   $f=fib($rec-1)+fib($rec-2);
   ```

   the value of `$rec` should not change after `fib($rec-1)` return.

   Therefore, `$rec=@_[0];` should be `my $rec=@_[0];`. Of course, it actually should be `my $rec = $_[0];` or `my $rec = shift;`.

Comment: i tried even that but still i face the same problem

Comment: @Programmer That is because in your `fib()`, `$rec` is global, it should be local.

Answer (score 2):

Besides replacing else by elsif in one place, make $rec a local variable:

```
sub fib
{
    my $rec=@_[0];

    print"In the subroutine rec is :".$rec."\n";
    if($rec == '0')
    {
        $f='0';
    }
    elsif($rec == '1')
    {
        $f='1';
    }
    else
    {
        $f=fib($rec-1)+fib($rec-2);
    }

    return $f;
}
```